# How should I connect this old fluorescent lamp?

Tags: wiring, light-fixture

How do I connect a fluorescent lamp with capacitors (or capacitor+starter?) and a ballast?

[image: picture of the circuit]

I made a diagram to make it clearer. lamppu = lamp and katto=ceiling.

[image: illustration]

I need to know where to connect these three cables that are loose from the capacitors and ballast.

Comment: What is that *lamppu*? A bare four-terminal fluorescent ("neon") tube? Or a two-terminal tube with integrated starter? Or does it have electronics? What does its manual say?

Comment: Thanks Janka! Lamppu is LAMP in finnish. Its a fluorescent lamp, without (i believe) an integrated starter. The lamp reads radium ralux duo 26w/827 - something like this: https://www.radium.de/en/products/compact-fluorescent-lamp-raluxr-duo-rx-d-26w830g24d . it was bought second hand, and no manual in it.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways of arranging a fluorescent tube circuit, one of the oldest ones is like this:

### Pre-Heat

[image: Pre-heat Fluorescent tube circuit]

A: Fluorescent Tube B: Power (+220 Volts) C: Starter D: Switch (Bi-metallic thermostat) E: Capacitor F: Filaments G: Ballast

Another is like this

### Semi-Resonant

[image: Semi-Resonant Fluorescent tube circuit]

There are other arrangements - see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluorescent_lamp#Starting)

Comment: OP's fluorescent bulb is a 2-pin  CFL.  I gather the twin-and-earth exiting to the right is to the lamp proper.

Comment: @harper Yes. Lamppu means lamp. I am still puzzled as i have a 2pin lamp (not a tube), and my ballast has only 2 cables. Added to that i am quite a dummy in reading those diagrams.

Comment: So as i understand the second wire of the ballast goes to the bottom connector together with the neutral wire of the lamp. And the capacitor+starter loose wires go to the live wire of the lamp. Does that sound right? then i can connect the ceiling live to lamp live and ceiling neutral to lamp neutral. Same with ground.

Comment: @Julia no, that would just be putting everything in parallel.   Placing the ballast in parallel with the lamp makes no sense.  Placing power in parallel with the lamp makes no sense (that would simply be direct feeding power onto the lamp).  Nothing goes to the earth terminal except green/yellow wires.  There's a 4th set of terminals on there for a reason, it must surely be used to place things in a different arrangement.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! I ended up just changing the socket and going for a new lamp. :/